# Caixa de texto para o range

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angularjs, css3

Olá, minha aplicação está em angularJs e também estou utilizando o materialize. Gostaria de criar um range mas ao lado dele colocar uma input que quando eu digito os dados a range muda com o valor do dado que digitei.

```
<div class="col s12 m10 l11" id="ramMemory-range">
    <div class="range-field ">
        <label>
            <span class="left">1GB</span><span class="right">64GB</span>
            <input type="range" name="ramMemory" id="ramMemory" min="1" max="64" class="validate" data- 
             error="#ramMemory-range" ng-model="server.ramMemory" required/>    
        </label>

    </div>
    <input type="text" name="valorRange">
</div>
```

Comment: e qual a dificuldade/duvida/problema?

Comment: Só gostaria de saber como eu faria isso... não tenho ideia... sou iniciante.Pdeira colocar um exemplo?

Comment: cria um valor de model para o input, depois criar uma function que vai ser acionada por exemplo com `ng-change` no input, que pegar o valor do input e seta na model do range

Comment: O ng-model da input pode ser igual ao da range? Ao mesmo tempo que posso mudar no range manualmente, posso mudar ela na input, ou seja ela vai receber o valor da input. Depois disso tenho salvar mandando assim para a  api e o banco

Answer (score 0):

Ficou Assim:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:2rem">
        <div class="col s12 m2 l1">
            <span>RAM Memory: </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m10 l11" id="ramMemory-range">
            <div class="range-field ">
            <label>
                <span class="left">1GB</span><span class="right">64GB</span>
                <input type="range" name="ramMemory" id="ramMemory" min="1" max="64" class="validate" data-error="#ramMemory-range" ng-model="server.ramMemory" required/>

            </label>

            </div>

        </div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="server.ramMemory" ng-change="valorRange(server.ramMemory)">
    </div>


$scope.valorRange = function(teste){
    $scope.server={
        ramMemory: teste

    }
}
```

Quando eu mudo o valor atraves do range o input recebe esse valor e muda de acordo com o valor recebido do range.
Quando tento mudar o valor atraves da input, dá erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ahh encontrei... Apenas tem que mudar o type da input para number

Comment: ou isso ou converte para numero ;)